# Why is this condition necessary/sufficient for a differential to be exact?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm talking about a differential such as:

$$dz=M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy$$

The condition being:

$$\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \right)_x=\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} \right)_y$$

I've seen this in plenty of thermodynamics textbooks. My guess is that this comes from the fact that $dz$ can also be defined as:

$$dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy=Mdx+Ndy$$

And following Clairaut's theorem the condition appears naturally. Is this essentially it?

Comment: Clariaut's theorem gives the necessity. Sufficiency (assuming the domain is simply connected, or for simplicity an open ball/rectangle/ star-shaped/ convex) is obtained by considering an explicitly defined $z$. FOr example, assume the domain is all of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Define $z(a,b)=\int_{\gamma_{(a,b)}}M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy$ where $\gamma_{(a,b)}$ is the straight line segment from $(0,0)$ to the point $(a,b)$. From here one can show (assuming $M,N$ are continuous functions) that $z:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ function and $M=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},N=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo You could post that as an answer